# How to show only 2 rows of UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Actually, I want to show only two rows in `UIPickerView` with more than 2 data. So, whenever the user scrolls up/down then the user can show only two rows.

Getting more idea of what I want by seeing below picture:

[image]

I have tried below code

```
 var pickerDataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4","5","6", "7", "8", "9","10","11","12"];
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    var label = view as! UILabel!
    if label == nil {
        label = UILabel()
    }
    let titleData : String?


    titleData = pickerDataSource[row]
    if row == pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    {
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Montserrat-Regular", size: 16.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGrayColor()])
        label.attributedText = myTitle
    }
    else
    {
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Montserrat-Regular", size: 16.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()])
        label.attributedText = myTitle
    }
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    return label

}
```

This will change the color of the row but how I set only two row.

Is there any way to achieve like that?

Comment: A picker view shows as many rows as it can fit in its view. Your only option is to tell the picker that your rows are really tall.

Comment: @rmaddy how to hide bottom row , Need to hide bottom of row from selected row

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scroll between two rows when you have many datas. But I have implemented a [`DLPickerView`](https://github.com/danleechina/DLPickerView), you can control the scrolling range with this picker view.